# removing numbers form list by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Take 5 integer input from the user.

1. Remove all numbers less than 9.
2. Calculate the sum of remaining numbers

   ```
       python
       n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
       a = list(map(int,input("\nEnter the numbers : "). strip(). split()))
       for i in range(len(a)):
         if a[i]>9:
           a.remove(a[i])
           b=sum(a)
           print(b)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove from same list, of course the index will be out of range items from list,

BUT you really don't need to remove those items from list, just don't include them in your sum calculation:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int, input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))
b = sum([num for num in a if num<= 9])
print(b)
```

Comment: In frist method,it again got an index error .I have to remove the element from the list because that's my question on assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want to remove numbers less than 10 from the list and Calculate the sum of the remaining numbers

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
a = list(map(int, input("\nEnter the numbers : ").strip().split()))

if len(a) == n:
    for num in a:
        if num < 9:
            a.remove(num)
    print('sum',sum(a))
else:
    print(f"You must enter {n} number")
```